# I know that we can pass a double for the float argument in a function. The question is should I do so?

Tags: types, arguments

I know that we can pass doubles for the float arguments in a function because of implicit conversions. The question is should I do so?

The function definition or prototype is:

```
void sf:Transformable::setPosition(float x, float y)
```

And I pass in those doubles as arguments:

```
spriteTree.setPosition(20, 0);
```

Should I do the up above or the below here?

```
spriteTree.setPosition(20f, 0f);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/type-conversions-and-type-safety-modern-cpp?view=msvc-170) (emphasis mine):

> When you write a C++ program, it's important to ensure that it's
> type-safe. This means that every variable, function argument, and
> function return value is storing an acceptable kind of data, and that
> operations that involve values of different types "make sense" and
> don't cause data loss, incorrect interpretation of bit patterns, or
> memory corruption. A program that never explicitly or implicitly
> converts values from one type to another is type-safe by definition.
> However, type conversions, even unsafe conversions, are sometimes
> required. For example, you might have to store the result of a
> floating point operation in a variable of type int, or you might have
> to pass the value in an unsigned int to a function that takes a signed
> int. Both examples illustrate unsafe conversions because they may
> cause data loss or re-interpretation of a value.